# I am not able to use suite variables across multiple test files

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, test-suite

I am initializing a suit variable in the initial suit setup by simply using,

```
Set Suite Variable    ${sample}    abc
```

in the **init**.robot. But the variable is not accessible in the next test file which is 01__test.robot.

```
Log To Console    ${sample}
```

The error says: `Variable '${sample}' not found.`

How to use suite variables in such a way that they are accessible within the whole test suite?

I tried different methods like using the variable section etc. It simply does not work.

Comment: suite variable won't work in this case as it exists for perticular .robot/suite file. instead use global variable. https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a simple solution for the above issue. We can simply set the suite variable in the initialization suite as below.

```
Set Suite Variable    ${sample}    abc     children=${True}
```

We can ser childern=${True} which allows us to use this variable across all the test files in the current suite.